# Why is my Java String matching this regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a snippet of code:

```
String textFieldContents = myJTextField.getText(); // javax.swing.JTextField

// If two consecutive pipes exist in the text, or if the text ends with a pipe, print a statement.
if(textFieldContents.matches("||") || textFieldContents.endsWith("|"))
    System.out.println("We have a winner!");
```

When the `myJTextField` text field (Swing component) is empty and has no text in it, the `We have a winner!` text prints. Why?

Comment: Because you're not escaping the special character `|`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, post an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is a special charactor in with regex, you would need to escape the charactors to use them literally.  You also need to absorb any preseding and trailing charactors if you just want to see if there are two consecutive pipes somewhere.

```
if(textFieldContents.matches(".*\\|\\|.*") || textFieldContents.endsWith("|"))
    System.out.println("We have a winner!");
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that [public boolean matches(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

You need to escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `|`.

(Escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`).

You can also use [Pattern#quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

`textFieldContents.matches(Pattern.quote("|"));`

See @JimDagg answer (+1) to understand why it always return *true* in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Maroun Maroun (+1) - one last followup: do I need to do the same with the `endsWith()` call? Or can I leave the pipe as-is?

Comment: No. *endsWith(String suffix)* expect a String and not a regex. See the link I provided to understand the meaning of `|` in regex.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character is a special character in a Java regular expression.  It's effectively an "or".  Your regex ends up saying "match either zero characters or zero characters", which is true everywhere in the string.  Escaping it with a backslash in the regular expression will solve the problem...

but backslashes in Java strings have special meaning too, so you have to *escape the backslash which escapes the pipe!*!   You end up having to use `\\|`, which will result in the regular expression `\|`, which yields a match on the pipe character, `|`.

Answer (score 0):

[String.matches()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) uses **regex to match** with the input String. In regex, **'|' has a special meaning** and it (used as ORing). So you need to explicitly escape this special character to make avoid being used as a special character.

Use something like this :

```
if(textFieldContents.matches("\\|\\|"))
```